# Data binding <select> element's selected index with Angular

Tags: html, angular

Could I please ask what I am doing wrong in the following:

Firstly, the following works fine:

I have the following variables in my .ts component:

```
public m_array = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
public m_selectedValueIndex = "two";
```

and in my html I have:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="m_selectedValueIndex">

    <option *ngFor = 'let num of m_array'>
        {{num}}
    </option>

</select>
```

All works fine, and I can see that I have two-way binding on m_selectedValueIndex.

But If I change to the code below things do not work as I expected they would:

.TS code:

```
public m_array = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
public m_selectedValueIndex = 2; // THIS IS NOW A NUMBER
```

html code:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="m_array[m_selectedValueIndex]"> // THIS IS NOW AN INDEX TO ARRAY

    <option *ngFor = 'let num of m_array'>
        {{num}}
    </option>

</select>
```

Initially it looks like it's working because the initially selected item is indeed the one with and index of m_selectedValueIndex. But if I use the list box then the values listed actually change.

I may initially have:

one
two
*three*
four

(where *italics* indicates that it is selected). This is as I would expect because m_selectedValueIndex = 2.

But if I click on any item (say "four" for example) then the listbox contents change to:

one
two
*four*
four

i.e. it is replacing item at index m_selectedValueIndex with my selection. Also the value of m_selectedValueIndex remains 2.

Just wanted to see if I could bind by index instead of value.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind the option value to the array's index using `[value]="ndx"`, (after defining it using `let ndx = index` within `*ngFor`)
like the following:

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="m_selectedValueIndex"> // THIS IS NOW AN INDEX TO ARRAY

  <option *ngFor="let num of m_array; let ndx = index" [value]="ndx">
    {{ num }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not working for me. Initially I now have no selection and whatever element I click on it replaces the element with index m_selectedValueIndex with the index. e.g. I start with the list showing "one","two","three","four" . If I click on "four" then the list now shows "one","two","3","four". It's changing the element at index 2 because  m_selectedValueIndex = 2, it's changing it to "3" because I clicked on the element at index 3.

Comment: Could you please create a simple [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) to understand exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sure, thanks for your help: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-craznq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks very much. It works. I will learn from that.

Comment: Thanks, you're most welcome! Could you please mark it as the accepted answer?